# EMBED SYSTEM [IDLE PYTHON]

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, embed

So i have an embed system working in the below code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('!emsay'):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="desc", color=0x00ff00)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

My problem is yes when i do !emsay it dose put the embed in but is there a way that after i put !emsay i can change the title and description without going into python to type out a whole new embed?
This is what i currently have:(im fine with this)[Discord screenshot of embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSPNp.jpg) I would like to make it so after i use the command !emsay i can enter a title and description through discord.
Thanks : )
sorry if iv overcomplicated this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!emsay'):
        count = 0
        def check(author):
            def inner_check(message):
                if message.author != author:
                    return False
            return inner_check

        while count < 2:
            if (count == 0):
                await message.channel.send("Write a title for embed")
                title = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
            elif (count == 1):
                await message.channel.send("Write a desc for embed")
                desc = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
            count += 1
        
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title = title.content, description = desc.content, color = 0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

If you don't write title and desc, you can get a TimeoutError and you can change timeout if you want.

[How to use?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Trds.png)

Comment: Thanks tried that but getting this error when trying to enter a title what should i do?

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kaii Hannam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\bots\test bot.py", line 26, in on_message
    title = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Oh sorry about that I forgot to change self.bot to client. I edited it right now. Can you try this again?